# Django - Dynamic unique test for a model field

Tags: python, django, model, unique

Is there a way to test for uniqueness of a field through a custom function?

Something like:

```
def custom_unique_test(instance):
    return global_test_results(instance)

class Category(models.Model)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=custom_unique_test())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your use case is that you only care about uniqueness within some relation with a larger group - eg, you don't need globally unique slugs, so `unique=True` is "too unique", you only need unique slugs for each `Category` within a `CategoryGroup`.

I'd suggest overriding `Category.save()`. You can check `self.pk` to see if this is an insert or update, and if it's insert, you can call your custom unique-check and slug-generation code before calling `super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.